# Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 login loop

Tags: login

I have a triple boot set-up:

Ubuntu GNOME
  Xubuntu
  Windows 7

Ubuntu GNOME login loops even with guest user. After installing Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 I didn't get the chance to install Nvidia Server Settings before having to reboot to a black screen. I purged all old drivers, installed correct Nvidia drivers 3.04.132(304) in terminal, and now I get this login loop at the login screen. I never had this problem in 2+ yrs. when I triple booted Windows 7, Linux Mint and Ubuntu 14.04  withGNOME shell. I've tried the `nomodeset` and ".Xauthority" tricks, but no dice. . .

```
lspci | grep VGA  

00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430] (rev a2)

dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia  

ii  libcuda1-304                                  304.132-0ubuntu0.16.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA CUDA runtime library
ii  nvidia-304                                    304.132-0ubuntu0.16.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.132
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-304                         304.132-0ubuntu0.16.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-settings                               361.42-0ubuntu1                               amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver

dkms status

nvidia-304, 304.132, 4.4.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-304, 304.132, 4.4.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-304, 304.132, 4.4.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I'm still fairly new to troubleshooting and solving errors. I've searched for answers and tried a few but nothing solved my issue.